# create a virtual environment in visual studio

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, virtualenv

I would like to create (using visual studio) a specific folder which contains the packages of the relative python project.
Now, i now that if i want to create a virtual environment i have to write those lines on the terminal:

- py -3 -m venv .venv      //where i specify the name of the virtual env
- .venv\scripts\activate

and then i start to write the names of the packages to download.

the problem is that the folder is created on the desktop but i want to create it somewhere else.
How can i change the folder path?

Comment: Go anywhere you want to have venv and execute commands in that directory and you will get a virtual env in that directory

Comment: The part about "*using Visual Studio*" is confusing because this has nothing to do with Visual Studio. For `venv`, the last argument you pass is the [/path/to/the/virtual/environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments). Change .venv to the full path you want.